# Is modifying my ArrayList in runOnUiThread thread safe?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin, thread-safety

I have an Activity that holds on to an ArrayList. The Activity will modify and access the ArrayList, but I would also like to access it from other Threads.

I am using runOnUiThread to accomplish this, but I am not sure if this is thread safe or not, or if there is a better way of doing this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var connectedSockets = ArrayList<Socket>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val port: Int
        serverSocket = ServerSocket(0).also { socket ->
            port = socket.localPort
        }

        Thread(Runnable {
            while (serverSocket != null) {
                serverSocket?.accept()?.let {
                    runOnUiThread {
                        connectedSockets.add(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start()
    }

}
```

Is connectedSockets thread safe in this case? Is there a more sensible way to do this or am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2):

It is safe unless you start to modify List from two different threads or whatever else that is not thread-safe. For such cases you must have only one thread where something will be modified from. If you will take something from the list and put something there from the same thread, then you'll prevent a situation with concurrent modification.

Comment: So as long as I always access this ArrayList from the UI thread, it should be safe?

Comment: @grez , actually it doesn't matter from which exactly thread you are going to modify this ArrayList, the main point is to modify it from a SINGLE thread. If you need to modify some collection of data from different threads and you don't wanna handle it on your own, then you surely should have a look at the concurrent collections.
For example, the Vector has the same functionality as ArrayList does, but it is synchronized (what means it is thread-safe).

Answer (score 0):

This code is not thread-safe for a number of reasons.

1. `connectedSockets` is public and mutable. You can change it to:

   `private val connectedSockets = ArrayList<Socket>()`
2. `ArrayList` by itself is not thread safe. And `Vector` is deprecated. You can use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, though.

   `private val connectedSockets = CopyOnWriteArrayList<Socket>()`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense that you create a separate thread and within the thread you force the code to be executed in the UI task. In fact you are not using multithreading

If you want to modify your ArrayList in a true separate thread and make it thread safe, create an instance like `Object myObject = new Object();` and enclose any code that modifies the ArrayList inside this `synchronize(myObject) {/ ** code that alters the list ** /}`

With this, only one task can modify the list at a time

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to understand this. Can you point me to a good resource to learn to use synchronize? I don't really understand how it works or how to use it for thread safety.

Also it looks like your code snippet is in Java, but no problem I can convert it to Kotlin.

Comment: Easy to understand, the code within the synchronize block can only be executed by one thread at a time, if at that time another thread tries to execute it, it will wait in synchronize () until the first one leaves the block. A good resource: https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized ,

Comment: Thank you Lluis Felisart. Can you help me to understand the first part of your answer? I think my use of a Thread makes sense. 

I have a while loop which will run for a long time, so I don't want to use the UI thread, however I want to use the same thread to modify or access connectedSockets, so that it cannot be modified in two threads at the same time.

Comment: the name `runOnUiThread` explains itself, your call to  `connectedSockets.add(it)` doesn't run in the Thread you created, it runs in the UI thread, then at all you are not using multithread when calling `add()`. What you get with the while loop is that the UI thread will be interrupted small fractions of time and surely it won't even be noticed. But if instead of add() you would call a method with a long process time, the UI will freeze.